# solve initial value problem ivp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have equations
\begin{align}
7z'(x) &= x^2 + y(x)^2 + z(x)^2  \\
y''(x) &= -(y'(x) + 7y(x))\sin(z(x))
\end{align}
where $$(y(0),y'(0),z(0))=(1.5,-2.6,0.5)$$

The task is to solve this problem using a computer.
Can someone help with explaining what goes in $u'(x)$?  Thanks.

I am guessing $u(x) = (y'',z')$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $y'(x) = u(x)$. Therefore $y''(x) = u'(x).$

Accordingly, the equation:

$$y''(x) = -(y'(x) + 7y(x))\sin(z(x)),$$

is transformed to:

$$u'(x) = -(u(x) + 7y(x))\sin(z(x)).$$

Finally, you get a set of first-order ODE:

$$\begin{cases}
y'(x) & = u(x) \\
u'(x) & = -(u(x) + 7y(x))\sin(z(x))\\
z'(x) & = \displaystyle\frac{1}{7}\left(x^2 + y(x)^2 + z(x)^2\right) 
\end{cases}.$$

Initial condition is just $(y(0),u(0),z(0))=(1.5,-2.6,0.5).$

Answer (score 0):

For the example of the book:
$$y''=y'\cos x +2y$$

Substitute $u_1=y ,  u_2=y'$
$$\implies u'_1=y'=u_2 $$
And,
$$ u'_2=y''=2u_1 +   u_2\cos x$$
With matrix notation we have:
$$\pmatrix {u_1  \\ u_2 }'=\pmatrix {0 & 1  \\ 2 &   \cos x}\pmatrix {u_1  \\ u_2 }$$
$$\pmatrix {u_1  \\ u_2 }'=\pmatrix {u_2 \\ 2u_1 +   u_2\cos x}$$
Or if you prefer with $u=\pmatrix {u_1  \\ u_2 }$
$$u'=\pmatrix {0 & 1  \\ 2 &   \cos x}u$$