# Approximate the solution of this initial value problem using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, maple, initial-value-problems

> We consider the following initial value problem for two functions $y(x),z(x)$:
>   \begin{align}
> 0&=y''+(y'+5y)\sin(z)
> \\
> 5z'&=x^2+y^2+z^2
> \end{align}
>   where $0≤x≤2$ and $y(0)=1.8$, $y′(0)=−2.4$, $z(0)=0.3$.
>
> Approximate the solution of this initial value problem using Euler's method with $100$ steps. (Hint: Rewrite the system of ODEs in standard form using a suitable substitution)

I need to get the final ODE, then I can use Euler's method in maple. I just don't know how to get the correct equation.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531838/115115, only the factor is not 5 but 7. Do the answers there address some or all of your concerns?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [solve initial value problem ivp](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3531838/solve-initial-value-problem-ivp)

Answer (score 0):

The aim of this exercise is to test that you understood the idea of a numerical ODE solution. Of how the input needs to be prepared and what the expected output is and how to interpret it.

A big hint to the solution is given with the initial conditions. They strongly suggest to use a state vector $u$ that has components $(y,y',z)$. In reversing this relationship, the ODE system can be written as a first order system
$$
u'=\pmatrix{u_1'\\u_2' \\u_3'}=F(x,u)=\pmatrix{u_2\\f(x,u)\\g(x,u)}
$$
This you can now insert into the Euler method
$$
u_{k+1}=u_k+hF(x_k,u_k)
$$

Plotting the result for 5,10 and 20 segments gives
[image]